# Eclipse 'greater than' sign under Mac os with hungarian wireless keyboard

Tags: eclipse, macos, editor

I have trouble with Eclipse under Mac Os 10.7, with a Hungarian apple wireless keyboard. 
According to Keyboard viewer I should press the ALT ( or Option is the name) + Shift + X to have the '>' sign. Like here, it is working, but inside Eclipse not.
I have searched at: Eclipse -> Preferences ->  General -> Keys. But I couldn't find a binding for a command to remove it. Maybe because I missed, since I can't search after key binging ( or I didn't found where to search ).

How can I have the possibility to enter the '>' sign with ALT + Shift + X ? or all times change to us layout and change back? :)

Is the any plugin to search commands by binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to delete the Run on server shortcut

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a shortcut for a *Run something* command, it was *Run Maven Build* for me by default on Eclipse Mars (4.5.2).

You can search for a binding at *General* -> *Keys* by first clicking into the *Binding* field, pressing ALT + Shift + X, then selecting it with your mouse (do not press any other key), then right click and Copy, then right click into the *filter text* field and Paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with: OPTION + SHIFT + 3 KEY OR 4 KEY IF YOU ARE IN MAC OS